# How to get the value of JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
this.mobj=document.getElementById(menu1)
var ob1 = this.mobj;
alert(" Obj value"+ob1.whichmethod());
```

In the alert I am getting "Drop menu Obj"+Object object
This is JavaScript.. If it was jQuery I could have done `$(this).attr('value')`. How to get the
value of JavaScript object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for more, but if you want the value property of the object in JavaScript, you can do it like this:

```
mobj = document.getElementById(menu1);
if (mobj){
    var obj_value = mobj.innerText; //or innerHTML;
}
```

If you're looking for the href of the hyperlink, you can get it like this:

```
mobj = document.getElementById(menu1);
if (mobj){
    var obj_value = mobj.href;
}
```

Comment: when i use this iam getting "undefined"

Comment: what's undefined? The object or the value? Are you making it into the if statement in the above example?

Comment: @Derby: What element is `menu1`, it may not have a `value`.

Comment: @Derby:"menu1" is hyperlink . i want to get the id of the hyperlink .by this id i can do any thing . I know this gets the id (this.mobj=document.getElementById(menu1))..but it is giving "object". I want to conver this object to value

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById(menu1).value` or `ob1.value`

Comment: when i use this iam getting "undefined"

Comment: @Derby: What element is `menu1`, it may not have a `value`.

Comment: the element (`menu1`) must have attribute `value`

Comment: Just curious, is `menu1` a variable or is that the id of the input element?

Comment: It should be string representing some id ... for example.. 
`var menu1 = 'menuIdGoesHere'`

Answer (score 0):

you can access the object properties by dot operator(.) or Square brackets([]).

For Example.

```
var pair = new Object();
 pair[0] = "value One"
 pair[1] = "value Two"
 pair[2] = "value Three"
 pair[3] = "value Four"
 pair["Five"] = "value Five"

you can use **pair.Five** or pair["Five"]
```